# Будьте толмачем. Template Toolkit -> ERB RUBY

Tags: ruby, шаблоны, erb

Привет друзья!

Увы по ЕРБ нет нормальной доки, раскиданные по инету страницы не отвечают на вопросы нормально. Там либо рельсы уже либо шлак.
Вот у меня и вопрос. Я вам приведу список команд которые я юзаю в Template Toolkit. А вы если можете перевидите мне их на ERB.

```
[% INCLUDE paging.tmpl %] - подключение внешнего шаблона

[% FOREACH key IN hash.keys %] - Мы итерируем хеш, и потом используем его 
  [% key %] is [% hash.$key %]   данные где надо
[% END %]

[% data.format(myvarwithdate,'%d.%m.%Y') %] - а вот так слабо?

[% FOREACH i IN top_menu %]
 [% i.data %]
[% FOREACH i.child %]
 [% data %]
 [% END %]
[% END %]
```

Comment: `[% data.format(myvarwithdate,'%d.%m.%Y') - а вот так слабо?` -- что, прям без `]`? Ой-вэй, да, наверное слабо.

Comment: да наверное слабо, если вместо ответа человек докапался до скобки. ну ну.

Comment: Ответ я уже пишу, но шаблон переводить будете сами. Я только опишу синтаксис ERB.

Answer (score 3):

По ERB документация правда так себе, но он сам по себе простой.

Гораздо лучше [документация у Erubis](http://www.kuwata-lab.com/erubis/users-guide.html), другого языка из того же семейства, но он более общий, поддерживает несколько языков и синтаксического сахара в нём немножко больше. Там есть что документировать хотя бы.

---

Но вернёмся к ERB. Он туп как пробка. Он берёт шаблон и собирает из него код на Ruby, пользуясь несколькими простыми правилами.

- `<% инструкция %>` — просто выполняет инструкцию, возвращаемое значение игнорирует, да и вовсе инструкция не обязана его иметь, к примеру у `<% end %>` его нет: так заканчивается начатое ранее выражение.

  - В генерируемый код выводится "как есть", только снабжается `;` в конце. Поэтому, скажем, `<% 2 + %><% 2 %>` из выйдет `2 +; 2`, синтаксическая ошибка. Но иногда посреди выражения `;` допустимо, например в вызове метода с блоком это позволяет отделить тело блока: `<% (1..5).each do |i| %><% puts i %><% puts '---' %><% end %>`
- `<%= выражение %>` — вычисляет значение выражения и выводит результат в документ.

  - `выражение` должно быть самостоятельным. `<%= 42.tap do %><% end %>` упадёт.
  - В генерируемый код выводится как "запись в поток вывода шаблона":

    ```
    _erbout.concat((выражение).to_s)
    ```
- `<%# комментарий %>` — игнорирует, что и положено делать с комментарием.

  - В генерируемый код не выводится вовсе.
  - Несмотря на то, что в Ruby комментарии начинаются тоже с `#`, это не то же самое, что `<% # комментарий %>`, такой записью лучше не пользоваться, т. к. она образует в сгенерированном коде Ruby-комментарий до самого конца строки. Поэтому такое: `<% # foo %><%= 42 >` сгенерирует код:

    ```
    # hi ; _erbout.concat \" 42 >\";
    ```

    Пол-шаблона стало комментарием и ничего не выводит, у-у-упс!
    `<%# foo %><%= 42 >` же работает верно.

Для случаев, когда на ERB нужно генерировать код на ERB (эдакий мета-ERB), `<%%` воспринимается как указание вывести `<%`, что позволяет экранировать все виды тегов для вывода, и даже (наверняка случайно) кое-что ещё:

```
 <%% %>  -> <% %>
 <%%= %> -> <%= %>
 <%%# %> -> <%# %>
 <%%     -> <%
 <%%>    -> <%>     при этом <% %> -> ~пустота~
```

Всё. Больше ничего в ERB нет. Все остальные фишки, что в нём есть, реализуются уже в Ruby: включение других шаблонов, обходы [хэшмапов](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-each), [массивов](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-each) и [многого другого](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html), вычисление сложных выражений.

Comment: Ну очень исчерпывающий ответ. Спасибо. Буду пытаться работать с ним.
Одно жаль, не понятно может вместо ERB лучше было бы подключить другой шабонизатор, а какой лучше, я вот не знаю. И жалко что родной Template Toolkit к нему не подключишь :) за столько лет привык.

Comment: А почему банальщина вводит его в ступор.

[mcve]<% @data.each do |header,link| %>
<li><%= header %></li>
<li><%= link </li>
<% end %>[mcve]

` `eval': (erb):8: unterminated regexp meets end of file (SyntaxError)
(erb):8: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
<% end ).to_s); _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
                                                    ^
 from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `result'
 from news.rb:66:in `<main>'`

Глухо с форматированием коментариев.

Comment: @DenisAntonov ERB можно использовать в чём угодно. Им генерят HTML, YAML, даже Ruby. Если у вас нет таких требований по форматам вывода, можно взять что-нибудь поспециализированее: HAML, Slim, Rabl, arbre, JBuilder, AMS (хотя он не совсем шаблонизатор...) или что-то ещё, в мире Ruby полно их.

Comment: @DenisAntonov потому что вы опять, по ходу, скобку забыли. Только угловую на этот раз, с процентиком. Видите `<%= link`?

Comment: Нууу, однажды я засяду за рельсы. И там мне придется использовать ERB. Так что придется однако терпеть и привыкать.

Comment: @DenisAntonov не факт, что прям придётся. К нему можно прикрутить другие шаблонизаторы. Конфигурацию тоже можно (возможно, и нужно) организовать без ERB. Хотя поначалу, конечно, учебные материалы будут заставлять.

Comment: Да точно забыл! А вот следующий вопрос. А почему он мне вывел данные вот так - <li>{:header=>"Forbidding Forecast, :link=>"http://www.npr.or ?

Comment: @DenisAntonov потому что это Ruby, а у вас там хэшмапы. При раскладывании `{header: 'a', link: 'b'}` по `|header, link|` получится `{header: 'a', link: 'b'}, nil`. Разобрать хэшмап в отдельные переменные по ключам в новых версиях Ruby (2.1+ вроде?) тоже можно, но чтобы узнать как, советую начать читать любую книжку по современному Ruby :)