# Сборка шаблона файла с помощью rake

Tags: ruby, инспекция-кода, rake

Впервые написал код на Ruby, хочу ревью. Проверял `rubocop`ом, он возражений не имеет.

UPD: я писал `rubocop rakefile`, а надо было `rubocop Rakefile`. Поправил всё, кроме слишком длинной строки. Что делать со строкой?

Задача: написать rake-команду для создания шаблона файла документации. Разметка и содержимое файла несущественны.

В заголовке файла — дата документа в формате `YYYY Month DD`. На заголовке — ссылка-якорь с датой в формате `YYYYMMDD`. Дальше копируется содержимое файла-шаблона.

Что вызывает мои сомнения:

- Правильно ли работаю с чтением и записью в файлы?

  - В частности, вместо построчного переписывания файла не стоило ли как-то целиком его скопировать? Функциональщина какая-нибудь есть для этого?
- Может быть, вместо шаблонизации строк, лучше было бы шаблонизировать весь файл? В Python я бы применил Jinja в этом случае.
- Я должен написать какой-нибудь help? Или все будут использовать `rake --tasks`?

Код `Rakefile`:

```
require 'date'

desc 'Begin new release notes'
task :rnotes, [:date] do |_t, args|
  if args.date
    date = args.date
  else
    puts 'Enter the date for the release notes in YYYYMMDD format: '
    date = STDIN.gets.chomp
  end

  filename = "release-notes/#{date}.md"
  puts "Creating new release notes: #{filename}"

  d = Date.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')
  longdate = d.strftime('%Y %B %d')

  open(filename, 'w') do |release_notes|
    release_notes.puts "## #{longdate} <a id=\"#{date}\" class=\"anchor\" href=\"#{date}\"></a>"
    release_notes.puts ''

    template = 'templates/rnotes.md'
    File.readlines(template).each do |line|
      release_notes.puts line
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Правильно ли работаю с чтением и записью в файлы?

**Почти хорошо, да.**

`Kernel.open` (который просто `open`) стоит заменить на `File.open`, если вы планируете открывать этим только файлы. Ибо метод из `Kernel` умеет не только это.

А ещё `readlines` вычитывает весь файл целиком в память и возвращает уже собранный массив из строк. Можно вычитывать файл построчно более ленивым итератором, вроде того, что возвращает `File#each_line`:

```
File.open(template) do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    release_notes.puts line
  end
end
```

> Может быть, вместо шаблонизации строк, лучше было бы шаблонизировать весь файл? В Python я бы применил Jinja в этом случае.

**Это неплохой вариант.** В стандартной библиотеке Ruby есть ERB, шаблоны на котором [состоят фактически из Ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/636472/181100). Но при текущей сложности форматирования пользы от этого будет немного. Переход станет оправданным только когда шаблон существенно усложнится.

> Я должен написать какой-нибудь `help`? Или все будут использовать `rake --tasks`?

Кроме `desc` (который у вас уже есть) в Rake средств нет. Можно разместить подобное описание задачи в ридми или иной вводной документации к проекту.

---

#### Теперь не о вопросах:

---

```
task :rnotes
```

От сокращения лучше воздержаться в пользу `release_notes`, если оно конечно не несёт в себе какого-то особенного смысла.

---

```
  if args.date
    date = args.date
  else
    puts 'Enter the date for the release notes in YYYYMMDD format: '
    date = STDIN.gets.chomp
  end
```

В Ruby `if` возвращает значение (в каждой области видимости возвращаемым значением становится значение последнего выражения), поэтому паттерны вида "`if X` присвоить одно `else` присвоить другое" обычно заменяются на безусловное присваивание, но с условным выражением внутри:

```
  date = if args.date
           args.date
         else
           puts 'Enter the date for the release notes in YYYYMMDD format: '
           STDIN.gets.chomp
         end
```

...а поскольку условие и первое возвращаемое значение совпадают, этот `if` успешно заменяется на `||`:

```
  date = args.date || begin # хватай args.date, а если его нет, то...
    puts 'Enter the date for the release notes in YYYYMMDD format: '
    STDIN.gets.chomp
  end
```

---

```
File.readlines(template).each do |line|
  release_notes.puts line
end
```

"Смотри как могу"

```
File.readlines(template).each(&release_notes.method(:puts))
```

Приём довольно нетипичный для Ruby, но работает. Хотели функциональщины? Вот вам щепотка points-free-стиля :)

`release_notes.method(:puts)` это метод `puts`, прибитый к "владельцу" (`release_notes`). Технически это объект класса `Method`, имеющий метод `call`, вызов которого приведёт к вызову соответствующего метода у соответствующего объекта с теми же аргументами.

Любой объект, имеющий метод `call`, можно передать в метод вместо блока, снабдив амперсандом, который обозначит, что это не просто аргумент, а блок (который в каждом вызове может быть только один).

Не могу рекомендовать этот приём, он не так уж часто встречается, т. к. его **не**использование частенько делает код читаемее. Сравните:

```
(0..9).map { |i| 7 + i }
(0..9).map(&7.method(:+))
```

---

Вот, вроде всё. Может ещё чего найду.

Comment: Применил всё, кроме функциональщины, на которую только полюбовался, но решил не применять.

Comment: `File.open(template).each do |file|` а зачем тут `each`? У меня же один файл. А его строки я перебираю во вложенном цикле.

Comment: @NickVolynkin мой косяк, там `.each` лишний, пофиксил.